# Create Payments, PHP

Tags: paypal

I'm using paypal to make my users able to payout their credits, which they can earn on my site. So i am actually buying my users efforts. As i have up to 200 payments per month, i would like to know, is there a possibility to send payments to my users via paypal api?

If yes, which methods should i use and what should i take care of? I possible i would also take a ready to go implementation in php.

I tried to check the documentation of the paypal api, but it was to complex, so i did not find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll be submitting payments to 200+ people at the same time, the [MassPay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/) API would work nicely for you, but you'll need to call PayPal to request it and get it specifically approved on your account.

If the users will be doing this on their own, one at a time, then you'll want to look at the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API, which is part of the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) platform.

You can use my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) to make the API calls very quick and easy for you regardless of which method you end up using.